# Javascript to do ssl pinning?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, https

Some employers use root certificate to intercept https. It's also pretty easy to do a man-in-the-middle with for example [Charles Proxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/).

I would like to create a script for my web page that checks if the client uses another certificate than the one I want to be used.

Do you know how to do?

Comment: If this virtual "man in the middle" can intercept HTTPS traffic they can surely replace the code that you use to check for a different SSL certificate. Here the SSL pinning has to happen on the side that the employer/MITM can't tamper with. Usually the browser - probably not, if they can install root certs on the computer.

Comment: Thanks @boxmein! My purpose is actually not to make the https traffic secure. I just want to check (purpose: journalism) if some employers use root certificate to intercept https. I thought that a test webpage would be a easy way! It's till hard to do?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check SSL certificate authority integrity in a javascript client, but you could do a more complex solution using a TLS library for both the client and the server done in node javascript, that shares a common library.

In this way, you can simplify the back-end and front-end code to check your TLS connections. So you can consider a good TLS node library for this task like [forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge).

Comment: Thanks @loretoparisi - my purpose is actually not to make the https traffic secure. I just want to check (purpose: journalism) if some employers use root certificate to intercept https. I thought that a test webpage would be a easy way! It's till hard to do?

Comment: @Kristoffer you want to check if some employee is doing a `mitm` attack?

Comment: Hi again, @loretoparisi! Not some employee - I mean employers. The companies - if they is doing mitm attack against the employees.